# Cannot clone my gitlab project to coda 2 on mac with https

Tags: macos, gitlab, coda

I've installed Coda 2 version 2.0.12 on my MacBook.

I've also installed GIT and registerd the path in Coda 2 preference "Git Tool path.
When I add a new site to Coda 2, I try to clone it from my Git repository, but it gives me an authentication failed error.
My local root is set to an empty folder.

The password that I use is the one of my Gitlab user, and it doesn't give any problem when I login to the Gitlab website.

Is this a Coda2 issue? Does someone have any workaround?

[image: Message I get]

Comment: What happens if you do it from the command line first?  Git should store the credentials in the keychain.

Comment: @trojanfoe it worked from command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enter the right username and password for your https access in the [coda settings](https://www.sweetprocess.com/procedures/104/setting-up-git-on-coda-2/#.VArKLGOiImI):

[image: https://sweetprocess-static.s3.amazonaws.com/site_media/media/13s02/39a57a2038c3b276a1ff5072c5df6995.png]

You need to select `https` as protocol.

Comment: I've tried to put my Gitlab user name as Nickname in Coda 2 site setting, but nothing has changed. I get the same error. Where do I have to select https as protocol? Isn't the Protocol in Site page the one for publishing the site on the web?

Comment: Where do I have to select https as protocol? In the protocol field of the Coda setting dialog, in the screenshot above.

Comment: I tried to choose "webDAV HTTPS" but nothing has changed. In the Source tab I already put the https link and my user password, but I get that error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've found a solution. Gitlab (and Github) says :
"If you used a non-default file path for your GitLab SSH key pair, you must configure your SSH client to find your GitLab private SSH key for connections to GitLab."
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths

Answer (score -2):

The target URI will become https://thetitan@github.com/thetitan/sourcecodedna.git. Now Git has a username to authenticate with.

Comment: There are multiple methods for authenticating a GitHub account. The URI you provided above does not support SSH or GPG keys. You can view/edit your SSH/GPG keys by logging into your GitHub account and going to the following URL: https://github.com/settings/keys. Also, it would be good to provide a link to documentation for the issue. Such can be found here for the question at hand: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github